# Method postToSystem() is automatically called on deployment in spring

Tags: spring

I have a simple Spring application, with a bean which contains a method with the name `postToSystem(parameters)` without any annotations and it is automatically called on deployment (and throws an exception). Could someone explain me what is the problem here? Is it the method name? The stacktrace when it is called is:

```
Daemon Thread [http-bio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-1] (Suspended (breakpoint at line 128 in CustomerExportServiceImpl))    
    owns: ConcurrentHashMap<K,V>  (id=93)   
    owns: Object  (id=94)   
    owns: StandardContext  (id=95)  
    owns: ManagerServlet  (id=96)   
    owns: SocketWrapper<E>  (id=97) 
    CustomerExportServiceImpl.<init>() line: 128    
    NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Constructor, Object[]) line: not available [native method] [local variables unavailable] 
    NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Object[]) line: 57    
    DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Object[]) line: 45    
    Constructor<T>.newInstance(Object...) line: 526 
    BeanUtils.instantiateClass(Constructor<T>, Object...) line: 148 
    CglibSubclassingInstantiationStrategy(SimpleInstantiationStrategy).instantiate(RootBeanDefinition, String, BeanFactory) line: 87    
    DefaultListableBeanFactory(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory).instantiateBean(String, RootBeanDefinition) line: 1000   
    DefaultListableBeanFactory(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory).createBeanInstance(String, RootBeanDefinition, Object[]) line: 953   
    DefaultListableBeanFactory(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory).doCreateBean(String, RootBeanDefinition, Object[]) line: 487 
    DefaultListableBeanFactory(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory).createBean(String, RootBeanDefinition, Object[]) line: 458   
    AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject() line: 295 
    DefaultListableBeanFactory(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry).getSingleton(String, ObjectFactory) line: 223  
    DefaultListableBeanFactory(AbstractBeanFactory).doGetBean(String, Class<T>, Object[], boolean) line: 292    
    DefaultListableBeanFactory(AbstractBeanFactory).getBean(String) line: 194   
    DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons() line: 626 
    XmlWebApplicationContext(AbstractApplicationContext).finishBeanFactoryInitialization(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory) line: 932 
    XmlWebApplicationContext(AbstractApplicationContext).refresh() line: 479    
    ContextLoaderListener(ContextLoader).configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ConfigurableWebApplicationContext, ServletContext) line: 389  
    ContextLoaderListener(ContextLoader).initWebApplicationContext(ServletContext) line: 294    
    ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent) line: 112 
    StandardContext.listenerStart() line: 4973  
    StandardContext.startInternal() line: 5467  
    StandardContext(LifecycleBase).start() line: 150    
    StandardHost(ContainerBase).addChildInternal(Container) line: 901   
    StandardHost(ContainerBase).addChild(Container) line: 877   
    StandardHost.addChild(Container) line: 632  
    HostConfig.deployWAR(ContextName, File) line: 1083  
    HostConfig.deployApps(String) line: 553 
    HostConfig.check(String) line: 1671 
    NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Method, Object, Object[]) line: not available [native method]  
    NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 57  
    DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 43  
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 606  
    BaseModelMBean.invoke(String, Object[], String[]) line: 301 
    DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(ObjectName, String, Object[], String[]) line: 819  
    JmxMBeanServer.invoke(ObjectName, String, Object[], String[]) line: 801 
    ManagerServlet.check(String) line: 1485 
    ManagerServlet.deploy(PrintWriter, ContextName, String, boolean, HttpServletRequest, StringManager) line: 709   
    ManagerServlet.doPut(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 450 
    ManagerServlet(HttpServlet).service(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 649  
    ManagerServlet(HttpServlet).service(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 727  
    ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 303  
    ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 208  
    WsFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 52    
    ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 241  
    ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 208  
    SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 108 
    ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 241  
    ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 208  
    StandardWrapperValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 220    
    StandardContextValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 122    
    BasicAuthenticator(AuthenticatorBase).invoke(Request, Response) line: 610   
    StandardHostValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 171   
    ErrorReportValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 102    
    AccessLogValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 950  
    StandardEngineValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 116 
    CoyoteAdapter.service(Request, Response) line: 408  
    Http11Processor(AbstractHttp11Processor<S>).process(SocketWrapper<S>) line: 1040    
    Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler(AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler<S,P>).process(SocketWrapper<S>, SocketStatus) line: 607   
    JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run() line: 314 
    ThreadPoolExecutor(ThreadPoolExecutor).runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) line: 1145  
    ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() line: 615   
    TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run() line: 61  
    TaskThread(Thread).run() line: 745
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- post-processors for all standard config annotations -->
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mydomain.service" />

        <bean id="jndiDataSourceLookup" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.JndiDataSourceLookup"/>
       <!-- + OTHER BEANS ARE ALSO DEFINED-->

</beans>
```

Spring version: 3.2.3

Comment: Can you post your Spring configuration?

Comment: I posted it. Also after changing the name, it is not called anymore...

Comment: After changing which name?

Comment: After changing the name of the method from `postToSystem` to e.g `httpPostToSystem`.

Comment: Hm, very interesting! It seems like Spring thinks that the method is an initialization method and invokes it. I'm trying to find some documentation on this

Comment: I could not reproduce this. Can you share a stripped down version of your project so I can test it?

Comment: Yes, but this evening.